# C# XML data into dictionary

Tags: c#, xml

Good Day,

I have been playing with the ToDicationary() extension method

```
var document = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\Info.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://www.someurl.org/schemas";

var myData = document.Descendants(ns + "AlbumDetails").ToDictionary
    (
        e => e.Name.LocalName.ToString(),
        e => e.Value
    );

Console.WriteLine("Writing music...");
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in myData)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

with the following XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Database xmlns="http://www.someurl.org/schemas">
    <Info>
        <AlbumDetails>
            <Artist>Ottmar Liebert</Artist>
            <Song>Barcelona Nights</Song>
            <Origin>Spain</Origin>
        </AlbumDetails>
    </Info>
</Database>
```

and I'm not getting the output I want.  Instead I'm getting this:

```
Writing music...
AlbumDetails = Ottmar LiebertBarcelona NightsSpain
```

Instead, I want myData("Artist") = "Ottmar Liebert", etc...

Is it possible to do with Descendants?

TIA,

coson

Comment: I don't think you can create a dictionary from `AlbumDetails`'s **descendants**. Artist,Song,Origin might happen not to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will simply get the `AlbumDetails` node:

```
document.Descendants(ns + "AlbumDetails")
```

You want *its* direct descendants (child nodes) - since these are also elements:

```
document.Descendants(ns + "AlbumDetails").Elements()
```

The full line would be:

```
var myData = document.Descendants(ns + "AlbumDetails")
             .Elements().ToDictionary(
                                      e => e.Name.LocalName.ToString(),
                                      e => e.Value
                                     );
```

Comment: Maybe not descendants but rather children (elements).

Comment: @JeffMercado - I don't believe `Children` is an extension method in LINQ to XML.

Comment: What I meant was that he probably wants to grab only the child elements of the `AlbumDetails` nodes, so he'd need the `Elements()` method, not `DescendantNodes()`.

Comment: @JeffMercado - Thanks for that, just as I found the documentation myself. Have not played with LINQ 2 XML much :)

Comment: Descendants will bring all childs (including sub childs) while Elements brings only immediate child. so it is safe to use Elements most cases. That said it depends on how the OP wants to take his data. But worth to mention

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
string s = "<data><resource key=\"123\">foo</resource><resource key=\"456\">bar</resource><resource key=\"789\">bar</resource></data>"; 
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument(); 
xml.LoadXml(s); 
XmlNodeList resources = xml.SelectNodes("data/resource"); 
SortedDictionary<string,string> dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string,string>(); 
foreach (XmlNode node in resources){ 
    dictionary.Add(node.Attributes["key"].Value, node.InnerText); 
}
```

Comment: Seems like you answer your *own* question instead of OP's one.

Comment: @L.B - Looks like answering the general question, using their own XML instead of that of the OP... And using `XmlDocument` instead of `XDocuement`, as the OP has.