# How can I convert an XML fragment to a Dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, fix-protocol

I have the following code for the method XmlToDictionary. But how to give input from a button, so that the XML data will be converted to Dictionary

XML Input

```
<messageTags>
  <tag key="35" value="U1" />
  <tag key="49" value="GEMI1" />
  <tag key="8" value="FIX.4.1" />
  <tag key="9" value="732" />
<messageTags/>
```

I want the output as below

```
35=U149=GEMI18=FIX.4.19=732
```

Code of XmlToDictionary()

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> XmlToDictionary(string key, string value, XElement baseElm)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (XElement elm in baseElm.Elements())
    {
        string dictKey = elm.Attribute(key).Value;
        string dictVal = elm.Attribute(value).Value;
        dict.Add(dictKey, dictVal);
    }

    return dict;
}
```

Code for button click()

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XElement xs = new XElement("messageTags", "tag");
    XmlToDictionary("23", "EUI", xs);
    richTextBox4.Text = XmlToDictionary("messageTags","tag",xs).ToString();                       
}
```

Comment: Have you actually checked that your input is as you say? You're creating a single XML element and passing it to your function. You aren't passing the whole structure.

Comment: Even if you have the dictionary, you can't just use `ToString()` to convert it to a FIX format. *Your code* has to construct the string. In fact, you don't need that dictionary at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# XML data into dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994369/c-sharp-xml-data-into-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *real* problem is that you want to generate a FIX message. You tried to do this by generating a dictionary (why?) and then calling `ToString()` on it. This won't work, because the default implementation of `ToString()` is to type the object's name.

You don't need to go through the dictionary at all, just parse the XML fragment and generate the final string from the tags. A quick and dirty attempt:

```
string fragment = "<messageTags>" +
                "<tag key=\"35\" value=\"U1\" />" +
                "<tag key=\"49\" value=\"GEMI1\" />" +
                "<tag key=\"8\" value=\"FIX.4.1\" />" +
                "<tag key=\"9\" value=\"732\" />" +
            "</messageTags>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(fragment);
var tags = from tag in doc.Descendants("tag")
           select String.Format("{0}={1}",
                                tag.Attribute("key").Value, 
                                tag.Attribute("value").Value);
var message = String.Join("",tags);
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

Will return `35=U149=GEMI18=FIX.4.19=732`

This attempt is dirty because it generates temporary strings, one for each tag pair. FIX is used in high throughput environments which means that performance *matters*.

A better approach would be to use a StringBuilder and a loop:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(fragment);    
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var tag in doc.Descendants("tag"))
{
    builder.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", 
                         tag.Attribute("key").Value, 
                         tag.Attribute("value").Value);
};
var message = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The StringBuilder() approach solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

Following code will give you a dictionary object with all values in XML

```
 private static void ReadXML2()
    {
        string sXML = "<messageTags>"+
                      "<tag key=\"35\" value=\"U1\" />"+
                      "<tag key=\"49\" value=\"GEMI1\" />"+
                      "<tag key=\"8\" value=\"FIX.4.1\" />"+
                      "<tag key=\"9\" value=\"732\" />"+
                    "</messageTags>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(sXML);
        var v = (from p in doc.Descendants("tag")
                 select p).ToDictionary(item => item.Attribute("key").Value,item=> item.Attribute("value").Value);
        Console.WriteLine(v.Count());

    }
```

Once the dictionary object is created, you can use your method to find a particular key/ value..

*By the way your XML string is wrong. You don't have a closing tag for messagetags*

**UPDATE**
Use following code which needs no Dictionary object

```
 var v2 = (from p in doc.Descendants("tag")
                 select p);

        string sOutput = "";
        foreach (var item in v2)
        {
            sOutput += item.Attribute("key").Value + "=" + item.Attribute("value").Value;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sOutput);
```

The output is

35=U149=GEMI18=FIX.4.19=732

Comment: Note that the OP asks for a FIX string that can be constructed from the parsed `doc` directly. Even with a valid dictionary the OP won't be able to get the string with `Dictionary.ToString()`

Comment: You should use a string builder, not concatenate strings. See [String Concatenation Vs String Builder Append](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972983/string-concatenation-vs-string-builder-append).

Answer (score 0):

See my version below.. keeping it as a callable method.

**UPDATED**

did it as you wanted but... i think there is an error in your request... look closely at '35=U149=GEMI18=FIX.4.19=732' how is what ever is doing to consume this gona know that GEMI18 is actaually GEMI1  [space]  8

```
  public static void DoStuff()
    {
        var stringXml = @"<messageTags> 
                                <tag key=""35"" value=""U1"" />
                                <tag key=""49"" value=""GEMI1"" />
                                <tag key=""8"" value=""FIX.4.1"" />
                                <tag key=""9"" value=""732"" />
                       </messageTags>";

        XmlDocument xmltest = new XmlDocument();
        xmltest.LoadXml(stringXml);

        XmlNodeList elemlist = xmltest.GetElementsByTagName("messageTags");

        var dic = XmlNodeListToDictionaryByAttribute("key", "value", elemlist);
        var test = DictToString(dic, "{0}={1}");
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, string> XmlNodeListToDictionaryByAttribute(string keyAttribute, string valueAttribute, XmlNodeList elemlist)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (XmlNode item in elemlist)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in item.ChildNodes)
            {
                var dictKey = childNode.Attributes[keyAttribute].Value;
                var dictVal = childNode.Attributes[valueAttribute].Value;
                dict.Add(dictKey, dictVal);
            }
        }
        return dict;
    }


    public static string DictToString<T>(IDictionary<string, T> items, string format)
    {
        format = String.IsNullOrEmpty(format) ? "{0}='{1}' " : format;

        StringBuilder itemString = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in items)
            itemString.AppendFormat(format, item.Key, item.Value);

        return itemString.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: The dictionary isn't really necessary. You can go from the XML to the FIX format without the dictionary, and make the code much cleaner.